# Comparator breaching general contract

Tags: java, sorting, comparator

The below code is a edited version of [Dave Koelle's AlphanumComparator](http://www.davekoelle.com/alphanum.html). The edit contains code which sorts empty strings to the end of the list, or bottom of the `JTable` in my case. The problem is a `java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Comparison method violates its general contract!` occurs.

To fix my problem I looked into it and found reasons such as the comparator doesn't have a `return 0;` in the correct place. I also found a comment in the Java [bug database](http://bugs.java.com/view_bug.do?bug_id=7193557) which read

> The sorting algorithm used by java.util.Arrays.sort and (indirectly) by java.util.Collections.sort has been replaced. The new sort implementation may throw an IllegalArgumentException if it detects a Comparable that violates the Comparable contract. The previous implementation silently ignored such a situation.
>   If the previous behavior is desired, you can use the new system property, java.util.Arrays.useLegacyMergeSort, to restore previous mergesort behavior

```
import java.util.Comparator;
import javax.swing.JTable;
import javax.swing.SortOrder;

public class AlphanumComparator implements Comparator<String> {
    JTable table;

    public AlphanumComparator(JTable table) {
        this.table = table;
    }

    private final boolean isDigit(char ch) {
        return ch >= 48 && ch <= 57;
    }

    private final String getChunk(String s, int slength, int marker) {
        StringBuilder chunk = new StringBuilder();
        char c = s.charAt(marker);
        chunk.append(c);
        marker++;
        if (isDigit(c)) {
            while (marker < slength) {
                c = s.charAt(marker);
                if (!isDigit(c))
                    break;
                chunk.append(c);
                marker++;
            }
        } else {
            while (marker < slength) {
                c = s.charAt(marker);
                if (isDigit(c))
                    break;
                chunk.append(c);
                marker++;
            }
        }
        return chunk.toString();
    }

    public int compare(String s1, String s2) {
        boolean swapInt = table.getRowSorter().getSortKeys().get(0).getSortOrder() == SortOrder.ASCENDING;

        int thisMarker = 0;
        int thatMarker = 0;
        int s1Length = s1.length();
        int s2Length = s2.length();

        if(s1Length != 0 && s2Length != 0) {
            while (thisMarker < s1Length && thatMarker < s2Length) {
                String thisChunk = getChunk(s1, s1Length, thisMarker);
                thisMarker += thisChunk.length();

                String thatChunk = getChunk(s2, s2Length, thatMarker);
                thatMarker += thatChunk.length();

                int result = 0;
                if (isDigit(thisChunk.charAt(0)) && isDigit(thatChunk.charAt(0))) {
                    int thisChunkLength = thisChunk.length();
                    result = thisChunkLength - thatChunk.length();
                    if (result == 0) {
                        for (int i = 0; i < thisChunkLength; i++) {
                            result = thisChunk.charAt(i) - thatChunk.charAt(i);
                            if (result != 0) {
                                return result;
                            }
                        }
                    }
                } else {
                    result = thisChunk.compareTo(thatChunk);
                }

                if (result != 0)
                    return result;
            }

            return s1Length - s2Length;
        } else {
            if(swapInt) {
                if(s1Length == 0) {
                    return 1;
                } else {
                    return -1;
                }
            } else {
                if(s1Length == 0) {
                    return -1;
                } else {
                    return 1;
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Would someone be able to help fix my problem and explain why this comparator is violating the Comparable contract

*Exception stack trace if needed*

```
Exception in thread "AWT-EventQueue-0" java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Comparison method violates its general contract!
    at java.util.ComparableTimSort.mergeLo(ComparableTimSort.java:744)
    at java.util.ComparableTimSort.mergeAt(ComparableTimSort.java:481)
    at java.util.ComparableTimSort.mergeForceCollapse(ComparableTimSort.java:422)
    at java.util.ComparableTimSort.sort(ComparableTimSort.java:222)
    at java.util.Arrays.sort(Arrays.java:1246)
    at javax.swing.DefaultRowSorter.sort(DefaultRowSorter.java:607)
    at javax.swing.DefaultRowSorter.setSortKeys(DefaultRowSorter.java:319)
    at javax.swing.DefaultRowSorter.toggleSortOrder(DefaultRowSorter.java:480)
    at javax.swing.plaf.basic.BasicTableHeaderUI$MouseInputHandler.mouseClicked(BasicTableHeaderUI.java:112)
    at java.awt.AWTEventMulticaster.mouseClicked(AWTEventMulticaster.java:270)
    at java.awt.Component.processMouseEvent(Component.java:6538)
    at javax.swing.JComponent.processMouseEvent(JComponent.java:3324)
    at java.awt.Component.processEvent(Component.java:6300)
    at java.awt.Container.processEvent(Container.java:2236)
    at java.awt.Component.dispatchEventImpl(Component.java:4891)
    at java.awt.Container.dispatchEventImpl(Container.java:2294)
    at java.awt.Component.dispatchEvent(Component.java:4713)
    at java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.retargetMouseEvent(Container.java:4888)
    at java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.processMouseEvent(Container.java:4534)
    at java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.dispatchEvent(Container.java:4466)
    at java.awt.Container.dispatchEventImpl(Container.java:2280)
    at java.awt.Window.dispatchEventImpl(Window.java:2750)
    at java.awt.Component.dispatchEvent(Component.java:4713)
    at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEventImpl(EventQueue.java:758)
    at java.awt.EventQueue.access$500(EventQueue.java:97)
    at java.awt.EventQueue$3.run(EventQueue.java:709)
    at java.awt.EventQueue$3.run(EventQueue.java:703)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.security.ProtectionDomain$JavaSecurityAccessImpl.doIntersectionPrivilege(ProtectionDomain.java:76)
    at java.security.ProtectionDomain$JavaSecurityAccessImpl.doIntersectionPrivilege(ProtectionDomain.java:86)
    at java.awt.EventQueue$4.run(EventQueue.java:731)
    at java.awt.EventQueue$4.run(EventQueue.java:729)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.security.ProtectionDomain$JavaSecurityAccessImpl.doIntersectionPrivilege(ProtectionDomain.java:76)
    at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEvent(EventQueue.java:728)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpOneEventForFilters(EventDispatchThread.java:201)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForFilter(EventDispatchThread.java:116)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForHierarchy(EventDispatchThread.java:105)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(EventDispatchThread.java:101)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(EventDispatchThread.java:93)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.run(EventDispatchThread.java:82)
```

Comment: do you have examples of input?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I think the problem is that your code never examines `s2Length` when `s1Length` is zero. You need to add another check to see if both strings are empty, like this:

```
if(swapInt) {
    if(s1Length == 0 && s2Length != 0) {
        return 1;
    } else if (s2Length == 0 && s1Length != 0) {
        return -1;
    } else {
        return 0;
    }
} else {
    if(s1Length == 0 && s2Length != 0) {
        return -1;
    } else if (s2Length == 0 && s1Length != 0) {
        return 1;
    } else {
        return 0;
    }
}
```

Your current implementation returns `1` or `-1` even when the two strings are empty (meaning that they must compare as equal and return zero). New sorting algorithm detects this problem, and throws an exception.

**Note:**

You should be able to simplify this code further by making `swapInt` an `int` that is either `1` or `-1`, depending on the `getSortOrder` result:

```
if(s1Length == 0 && s2Length != 0) {
    return swapInt;
} else if (s2Length == 0 && s1Length != 0) {
    return -swapInt;
} else {
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: @Dan Edited. Thanks!

Comment: @JBNizet Thank you!

Comment: @dasblinkenlight Just to quickly check, is this the right way to cast swapint to from a boolean to an int, `int swapInt = (table.getRowSorter().getSortKeys().get(0).getSortOrder() == SortOrder.ASCENDING)  ? 1 : -1;`?

Answer (score 2):

Your comparator does:

```
if (s1Length != 0 && s2Length != 0) {
    ...
} else {
    if (swapInt) {
        if(s1Length == 0) {
            return 1;
        } else {
            return -1;
        }
    } else {
        if(s1Length == 0) {
            return -1;
        } else {
            return 1;
        }
     }
}
```

So, if it doesn't enter the `if` block, it means that at least one  string is empty. But both could be empty. But your comparator only returns -1 or 1 in that case. Which means that if A and B are both empty, and comparing A to B leads to -1, then comparing B to A will also lead to -1, and A is thus both smaller and greater than B at the same time.

Just start your else block with

```
if (s1Length == 0 && s2Length == 0) {
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Thank you for the answer